# Diagonal of sparse 4D matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

This is question is the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61826786/numpy-symmetric-4d-matrix-construction), but for a sparse matrix (scipy.sparse). The solution given to the linked question used indexing schemes that are incompatible with sparse matrices.

For context I am constructing a Jacobian for a large discretized PDE, so the `B` matrix in this case contains various relevant partial terms while `A` will be the complete Jacobian I need to invert for a Newton's method approximation. On a large grid `A` will be far too large to fit in memory, so I want to use sparse matrices.

I would like to construct an array with the following structure:

`A[i,j,i,j,] = B[i,j]` with all other entries 0: `A[i,j,l,k]=0 # (i,j) =\= (l,k)`

I.e. if I have the `B` matrix constructed how can I create the matrix `A`, preferably in a vectorized manner.

Explicitly, let `B = [[1,2],[3,4]]`

Then:

```
A[1,1,:,:]=[[1,0],[0,0]]
A[1,2,:,:]=[[0,2],[0,0]]
A[2,1,:,:]=[[0,0],[3,0]]
A[2,2,:,:]=[[0,0],[0,4]]
```

Comment: `scipy.sparse` matrices are only 2d!  First line in the docs: **SciPy 2-D sparse matrix package for numeric data.**

Comment: @hpaulj thanks! This was just a hack anyways to create the jacobian as a 4D matrix (I would then reshape to 2D).

Comment: I'll have to figure out how to just directly construct the block diagonal form.

Comment: You could make the dense 4d, reshape it to 2d, and make a sparse from that.  That may give you some clues as to how to construct the sparse directly.